# How do I open or convert a BDOC file?

Tags: c#, filereader

I have a bunch of files I'm trying to convert. They are stored as binary data in a database (urghh!) I can convert them to a file in a folder but I sadly don't have the original format information.

I did the classic and renamed the files with a `.txt` extension and opened the file with notepad. The first few chars usually tells you what the file is. In my cases the first few chars are `BDOC`

A bit (well a lot) of googling suggests its a zip file, which kind of bears out as you can see the headers in the file suggesting that, but renaming to `.zip` didn't work.

More googling suggests it's a signed file and a format proprietary to the software that created it. And some weird software from Estonia (I didn't know they were famed for their software).

I've even tried renaming the file to various random formats with no joy.

I'd love to upload the file but its a personnel file with confidential information in it

All I'm looking for is a few pointers if anyone can help out.

Comment: https://www.skidsolutions.eu/repository/bdoc-spec212.pdf

Comment: @RQDQ. Thanks for that. I should have mentioned I did already find that PDF (my bad), it didn't provide much help. I don't much fancy writing a converter